# "jsonlint: command not found", although jsonlint IS installed

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, execute-command, json

I am interested in using `jsonlint` on commandline in my Ubuntu 16.04 OS. So I executed

`sudo apt-get install jsonlint`

and I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jsonlint is already the newest version (1.4.0-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

But then when I tried to execute

```
jsonlint -v packets.json
```

I got

```
jsonlint: command not found
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

The command is called `jsonlint-php`

Answer (score 3):

You could also try a different way to use jsonlint.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-demjson
$ jsonlint-py -f packets.json
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 (focal) LTS (on WSL) the package name has changed for `python3` and it maps to the normal `jsonlint` name:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install python3-demjson
$ jsonlint -f packets.json
```